Need to set Buffer values on Windows Security Event Log
Working on Domain Controllers running Windows Server 2022 21H2
I am getting a slew of Event 521 in Security log on about half of my DCs. The status code is 80000005, which I am told is a buffer overrun that can be resolved by increasing the Buffersize and MaximumBuffers in the Windows Registry.
I made that change in
HKLM/System/CurrentControlSet/Control/WMI/Autologger/EventLog-Security

Set BufferSize to 256 and MaximumBuffers to 64, and then rebooted. The 521 Events continue to accumulate and trigger Critical Alerts in ADAudit.
When I check the Security Log settings via PowerShell with this:
get-winevent -ListLog security -computername dc-deadhorse-vm | fl *

I get this info back:

FileSize : 497094656
IsLogFull : False
RecordCount : 378351
LogName : Security
IsEnabled : True
LogFilePath :%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\Security.evtx
MaximumSizeInBytes : 537067520
LogMode : AutoBackup
ProviderBufferSize : 64
ProviderMinimumNumberOfBuffers : 0
ProviderMaximumNumberOfBuffers : 16
ProviderLatency : 1000
ProviderControlGuid :

Note that the BufferSize and MaximumBuffers appear to still be at the default values of 64 and 16 respectively, which would explain why changing the registry as I did made no difference.
Is this correct? What is the proper method to set these buffer values?
For additional information, I also did the following as advised on other forum discussion about event 521, all resulted in no change:

Increased Log Size to 1GB

Enabled AutoArchive

Cleared the Security Log

Deleted and re-create the Security .evtx file

Confirmed permissions on the .evtx file

Confirmed adequate disk space

Rebooted the DC


Your input is appreciated!

I am told is a buffer overrun that can be resolved by increasing the Buffersize and MaximumBuffers Who told you that?

Elizabeth Green on Stack Exchange

It appears as if the correct registry location to adjust these values is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Security.
There you would add REG_DWORD values for BufferSize (in kb) and MaxBuffers (# of buffers).
The default for BufferSize appears to be 64, and for MaxBuffers 20. There isn't much information on this available, so I can't guarantee that this works. I've never had to configure this on Windows, and I've been working with it for 25+ years.
You'll definitely have to reboot after setting this, I don't think you need to clear the event log or anything like that. Let us know if that helps.

Thanks, Luke.  I just reached 35yr in IT myself and haven't encountered problem like this.  I appreciate your suggestion and will give it a shot.
Update will follow.

Question comes to mind;  Is the number of buffers value "MaxBuffers" or "MaximumBuffers"?
I see it as the latter elsewhere in the registry.

I don't think it would hurt to try both, I'm not sure to be honest which is used. They both sound compelling but it's possible I got that wrong and it's MaximumBuffers.

Got a chance to make changes on one of my DCs;
Added DWORD BufferSize = 256 and MaxBuffers = 64 and then rebooted.
Has not changed the frequency of 521 Events in the Security Log
Going to try MaximumBuffers and see if that changes anything.

So, it appears that MaxBuffers is the correct DWORD.  When I use MaximumBuffers, set at 64, a query of the Security Log settings shows the default of 16
Found via PowerShell
Get-WinEvent -ListLog Security | fl *
Changing the DWORD to MaxBuffers changes the query results showing the value of 64 as I set it.
Bad news is the change did not stop the 521 Events.

Thanks for confirming that, at least we know that it's the correct value. How many events/sec do you get in the log? Did you increase the BufferSize too? Also pls consider voting up.

It's not huge but is enough to piss-off ADAudit with Critical Alerts.  Checking just now @ the DC I'm testing on; we got 1233 Event 521 and a maximum of 10 events per second.   Came in like: Four in a second, two in the next second, two seven seconds later, two more two seconds later, two more three seconds later, ten in the next second, two in the next second, four two seconds later and so on.  Sometimes up to 40 seconds without an Event.  584 times we got 4 events in one second.  1200 times it was 2 in a second.

BufferSize = 256 MaxBuffers = 64
I voted you up and gave you credit for the answer on the other forums I posted this on - Experts Exchange, SpiceWorks, Microsoft etc.

Hey, Luke.  Would you have some thoughts on the Bufffer Size?  There is a Microsoft document which specifies that the code 80000005 is STATUS_BUFFER_OVERFLOW, and describes it
"{Buffer Overflow} The data was too large to fit into the specified buffer"
Do you know what the maximum value I can put into BufferSize is?

I'm honestly not sure, there is not much info available online and I am starting to wonder if those settings only affect event tracing for Windows, ETW. It's a bit concerning that you have tweaked the settings and they haven't improved the situation. What is the size of the security event log currently, is it 4Gb?

My Original Question was how to correctly set the BufferSize and MaximumBuffers on the Windows Security Event Log. To confirm what Lucky Luke recommended, here's how you do it:
Edit registry key:
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Security

Add DWORDs BufferSize and MaxBuffers with your values—multiples of 64, such as 128 and 32 respectively—then reboot.
After reboot, you will find that these values are updated when you query with this PowerShell command:
get-winevent -ListLog security -computername dc-deadhorse-vm | fl *

